# Databricks notebook how to stop truncating numbers when export the query result to csv

Tags: csv, download, databricks, truncate, aws-databricks

I use Databricks notebook to query databases and export result with long digit numbers to csv. I just accidentally close a pop-up window asking if need to truncate the numbers, I accidentally chose yes and don't ask again. Now all my numbers are truncated. I tried to change the settings in Databricks and Chrome browser, still not working.
Does anyone know how to enable that pop-up window again so that i can disable truncation when export/download numbers.

thanks!
J